# watch command to delete files in a directory every N secs

Tags: shell, wildcards, watch

I thought of using watch command to delete files in a directory every N seconds with the command running in background.

This is what I was planning to use:

```
nohup watch -n1200 rm -rf /var/log/radius/radacct/8.44.25.17/detail-2013* &
```

It works, but when I see the running process, it shows me the following output -

```
[root@Free-Radius 8.44.25.17]# ps -aef | grep watch
root     27326 10649  0 15:23 pts/0    00:00:00 watch -n1200 rm -rf /var/log/radius/radacct/8.44.25.17/detail-20130816
root     27404 10649  0 15:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep watch
```

Now there will be a new file `detail-20130817` tomorrow, which will not get deleted. Is there a way to achieve it using watch command. I know its easily doable using a simple bash script or cron job, but just wanted to know if it can be done using watch.

Comment: use rather `.../detail-$(date +%Y%m%d)`

Comment: Or configure the application to not write any logs, if you're just going to delete them anyway.

Comment: You should use `watch 'rm -rf something*'` to avoid the expansion of `*` by the shell before the execution of `watch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the `watch` command from `procps` (which starts a shell to interpret the command line that's made out of the concatenation of its arguments), use:

```
nohup watch -n1200 'rm -rf /var/log/radius/radacct/8.44.25.17/detail-2013*' &
```

With some other implementations, you may have to call the shell manually:

```
nohup watch -n1200 sh -c 'rm -rf /var/log/radius/radacct/8.44.25.17/detail-2013*' &
```

Why not use `cron` though?